# All taxonomy term paths default to the www.example.com root directory

Tags: taxonomy-terms, uri

After creating a new vocabulary and adding terms to it, clicking on the view tab of the term edit form sends me back to my root directory. And, of course, typing the term path in the url results in a page not found error message. What is going on?
Strangely enough, not too long ago, I created a vocabulary and it still works well (clicking on the view tab takes me to the term page view.) However, older vocabularies no longer work when hey used to.
Does anyone know what is going on?
Any help on this one would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have pathauto module installed, you might want to check the taxonomies aliases go to "/admin/config/search/path/patterns" and look for the old Vocabularies and see how the path is setup. moreover you might want to delete all aliases and do a bulk update for theme "/admin/config/search/path/delete_bulk" then "/admin/config/search/path/update_bulk".